# iPhoneX - UITextField in UIAlertController layout collapse by screen rotation

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x

I tried to use UIAlertViewController contains UITextField.
But, after carrying out the following procedure, I confirmed that the layout collapses.

```
// In Swift
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

1. Write this code about UITextField in UIAlertController
2. Execute this code at  iPhoneX simulator
3. As the alert displaying with software keyboard, rotate portrait to landscape.

Why did the layout collapse?

[screenshot: portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTt9G.png)

[screenshot: landscape(collapsed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJGsD.png)

Comment: Xcode version 9.2

Comment: Please add some screenshots.

Comment: I tried with your code in iPhone X in both landscape and portrait mode, it's layouts are not collapsed. Just the alert appears above the keyboard. Do you want to have the alert in centre of the screen ? @yuki43min

Comment: Does it only happen in iPhone X?

Comment: I added a screen shot link, so please check it.
This layout issue is only occurred on iPhoneX (Simulator and Device).